# Solve For The Word (1)

Tags: word

What is the word?

```
4     8     2     2

3     2     3     1

7     0     4     3

5     1     2     3
```

Hints

> - vertical
>
>  - k = 11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding numbers on the same row and using A1Z26 I've got

> PINK

Comment: correct answer yay

Answer (score 0):

Add all numbers by Row wise and convert those numbers in to Alphabets.

4+8+2+2 = 16

3+2+3+1 = 9

7+0+4+3 = 14

5+1+2+3 = 11

The 1 WORD

> PINK

If we add all numbers by Column-wise based on hint (Vertical K=11), convert in to Alphabets

C1=4+3+7+5=19

C2=8+2+0+1=11

C3=2+3+4+2=11

C4=2+1+3+3=9

> SKKI (means travel over snow on skis - Skii Trikke)

Comment: Isn't this exactly what Alex Eisenhardt's answer says? Before posting an answer, please check to see whether it adds anything new to what's already there.